# Make [capacity] a synonym of [memory]

Tags: discussion, tagging

Currently [capacity](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/capacity) has nine questions and [memory](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memory) has 86. Both have no wiki.

I suggest to make [capacity](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/capacity) a synonym of [memory](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memory) (they cover the same topic, but we should keep the lemma).

Comment: But they aren't synonyms. Memory isn't the only thing TeX can run out of.

Comment: @cfr: Then *please* go ahead and fill up their tag wikis (which are currently empty) with clear and *distinct* descriptions.

Comment: I'm not sure they are distinct, in the sense that anything tagged `memory` might be tagged `capacity`. But not anything tagged `capacity` should be tagged `memory`. What's a tag wiki?

Comment: @cfr: The tag descriptions. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/tagging